# Is 'where do you sit' idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage

I often use the expression

> Where do you **sit** on the second floor?
>
> Where does the clerk **sit** here in this building?

Obviously I use the verb sit to mean **location**?

> What is your location at work?

'Sit' expression is the exact translation of the phrase I would use in my native language.

So Is my expression idiomatic?

Edit:
If it is not, what is idiomatic phrase to say it

Comment: By *idiomatic*, you mean the most natural way to express your idea in English, right?  If you could confirm that this is correct (or incorrect), it would help clarify your question.  Unfortunately, *idiomatic* can mean more than one thing, and I think J.R. interpreted it the other way in his answer.

Comment: I meant what would a native speaker say? @snailboat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it's only idiomatic if the person doesn't normally sit at their workstation. Hence, in the context of an office, it's *not* idiomatic, but, in the context of a salon (where the hairdressers generally stand while they work), then it *could be* considered idiomatic.

The real question is, are there contexts where you'd use the phrase "where someone sits" if they are not generally sitting down in that location? For example:

> The pickers take their baskets to the roadways, [where the foreman sits](http://books.google.com/books?id=9lBJAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=%22where%20the%20foreman%20sits%22&source=bl&ots=K5NUjJTSok&sig=i-EVuaDJs6YY8TWq3lUE-7LGYc0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3u4xUqDDJqTD4AOT0IHwAg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22where%20the%20foreman%20sits%22&f=false) with several women and a number of baskets of about a bushel capacity lined with canvas.

Does that foreman have a chair at the side of the road? If not, I may have just found the phrase used as an idiom.

That all said, if you want to ask where somebody works, then asking:

> Where do you sit on the second floor?

is perfectly fine.

Comment: Wait.  Why is it only idiomatic to ask where they sit *if they don't normally sit*?  I'm confused.

Comment: @snailboat I think he means it's just a question if you're asking where they sit (ex "Where is Jill's desk?"/"Where does Jill sit?") but it's a "set phrase" that means "where is Jill located" if the word "sit" is used in contexts where people aren't actually sitting (you just want to know where they're located). "Where does the desk sit?" (Okay, I could have probably thought of a better example for the last one, but it eluded me.)

Comment: Oh, I get it.  My definition of *idiomatic* here was *"(linguistics) (of language) grammatical and natural to native speakers of a language"* ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idiomatic)), but J.R. meant *"a group of words whose meaning cannot be predicted from the meanings of the constituent words, as for example (It was raining) cats and dogs"* (ibid).  I think Tim is using the former definition, not the latter; he presumably wants to know what the natural way to ask his question is.

Comment: [My car sits in the driveway.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22car+sits+in+the+driveway%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) Is that really "idiomatic"?

Comment: @Fumble, I would say no, because that's one standard definition of the word "sit". ([Collins #6 – or #11, if the car doesn't run](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sit)).

Comment: Does that imply if a particular figurative sense of a word happens to be in the dictionary, it's not "idiomatic"? I don't think that approach will work, since *most* well-known idiomatic usages are listed in most dictionaries.

Comment: @Fumble: No, I am merely talking about idiomatic expressions, as defined in snailboat's comment. Indeed, most idiomatic usages _are_ listed in the dictionary, but as separate idioms, like [_sitting pretty_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sitting-pretty#sitting-pretty_2), for example.

Comment: I guess I dissected the O.P.'s question like this: Q:  Is "Where do you sit?" idiomatic, in the context of "Where do you sit at work?" Ans: If you _are_ sitting at work, it wouldn't be an idiom, it would just be a question. If you _don't_ sit at work, then it _could_ be considered an idiom, but that might be a stretch. I'm trying to figure out if I'd ever ask, "Where does Paula sit?" when I mean "Where does Paula work [but rarely sit]?" It's a thorny problem, which is why I've upvoted the question. I hope others answer, too; this could get good :^)

Comment: Different people will have different opinions, I'm sure. But if we assume by *"idiomatic"* OP means *"sounds reasonable to native speakers, who would be likely to use the form themselves"*, I think the answer is *"Yes, people may well ask where you **sit**, if **sitting** is what you normally do there"*. But if you normally lie or stand there, I don't think many if any native speakers would use ***sit*** "figuratively" to mean "be located somewhere" (when talking about a *person*, for whom the *literal* sense could feasibly apply).

Comment: ...unless we're getting *highly* figurative, in contexts like [where you sit in the hierarchy](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22where+you+sit+in+the+hierarchy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), with no real possibility of it being interpreted literally.

Comment: @J.R. So I think we have concluded that if I am talking about a guy who sits in cubicle like a standard office guy, in that scenario 'where do you sit' sounds okay?

Comment: @Tim - Yes, that part was easy. If by "idiomatic" you meant "does this sound natural to the native ear," then the wording is fine. I think I may have overanalyzed your use of the word "idiomatic" here. :^)